# How to use single js/css file in frontend and backend in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, backend, frontend, skin

I have to use a frontend js file in backend.Currently file is at

/skin/frontend/default/test/js/v1.js

and if I want to use it in backend I have to move it to

/skin/adminhtml/default/default/js/v1.js

but I don't want to duplicate it. So where should I place it. And what should be path in

```
<action method="addItem">
           <type>skin_js</type>
           <name>path of js file/v1.js</name>
</action>
```

Comment: "and if I want to use it in backend I have to move it to /skin/adminhtml/default/default/js/v1.js" yes that the only correct way to do so.you can not use front js in admintml in layout file.if you want to add ,do add it in your template file by providing front end js path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your file in js/yourfolder/v1.js you can use same for both admin and frontend

```
<action method="addJs">
                <script>yourfolder/v1.js</script>
            </action>
```

Comment: He don't want to duplicate the file.

Comment: I don't understand , what are you saying. I said I don't want to make an other copy of file. I want to use original file which is @/skin/frontend/default/test/js/v1.js

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar added comment

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar updated the answer..

Comment: @QaisarSatti " js/yourfolder/v1.js" you mean js in main project

Comment: yes main js folder..

Comment: @QaisarSatti that doesn't work for me

Comment: did you use `<global>
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>yourfolder/v1.js</script>
            </action>

        </reference></global>` this will add in all page

Comment: I don't have to add it for all pages, both frontend and backend modules are my custom modules

Comment: `<modulename_controllername_actionname>
<action method="addJs"> <script>yourfolder/v1.js</script> </action> </reference></modulename_controllername_actionname>` add it like that then it only will work for custom module

Comment: try to refresh the cache if is enable..

Comment: @QaisarSatti how should I do that.

Comment: you are seeing the tick sign with my answer click on that.

Comment: visit tour and you will get the idea `http://magento.stackexchange.com/tour`

Comment: and what about the css file ? can be included both admin and frontend ?

Comment: @AttilaNaghi for the css you have to add in `skin/adminhtml/default/default/` for admin and for  frontend `skin/frontend/base/default/`

Comment: The idea is that I do not want to have the same file in 2 different place. Because that file I needed in both admin and frontend

Answer (score 3):

That's easy. Just follow below steps:

1. Move v1.js in js directory as /js/v1.js
2. Access this file from both frontend & backend using below command in your layout xml file

>

```
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>v1.js</name></action>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try same as bellow code in your frontend & backend layout file

**frontend layout file**

```
<default>
      <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>test/test.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

**backend layout file**

```
<default>
      <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>test/test.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: How is it possible, you are trying to access same form two different places with same path, with out placing it on specific point

Comment: This will add js from js folder only and not from skin_js

Comment: have you used one form in frontend & second in backend right?

Comment: in magento  js/prototype/prototype.js is use forntend and also backend

Comment: you are follow same as prototype.js  (location at forntend  app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\page.xml and backend  app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\main.xml